# Check existing password and reset password

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

views.py to save the password:

```
elif 'reset_password' in request.POST:
    if request.POST['reset_password'].strip():
    saveuser = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
    saveuser.set_password(request.POST['reset_password']);
    saveuser.save()
    userform = UserForm(instance=saveuser)
    return redirect('incident.views.about_me')
```

popup box to get the old password and new password

```
<div id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
    <form  method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Reset Password</h2><br />
        <table>
      <tr><td>Enter your old password</td><td>
        <input type="text" name="old_password" id="old_password" maxlength="30" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Enter your new password</td><td><input type="text" name="new_password" id="new_password" maxlength="30" /></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Confirm your new password</td><td><input type="text" name="reset_password" id="reset_password" maxlength="30" /></td></tr>
      </table>
        <div style="width:180px;float:right;margin:20px 5px 0 10px">
            {% include "buttons/save.html" %}
            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" id="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-back.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" />
            Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am able to save the new password,but i want to know the following things

- How to check the entered old password is correct with existing password.
- How to validate new password field and confirm password field.Which validation is better to perform.

Need some help.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you would check for old password - before the `set_password`,

```
user.check_password(request.POST['reset_password'])
```

Also, check for password confirmation in the following way.

```
elif 'reset_password' in request.POST:
    old_password = request.POST['old_password'].strip()
    reset_password = request.POST['reset_password'].strip()
    new_password = request.POST['new_password'].strip()

    if old_password && reset_password && reset_password == new_password:
        saveuser = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
        if user.check_password(old_password):
            saveuser.set_password(request.POST['reset_password']);
            saveuser.save()

            userform = UserForm(instance=saveuser)

        return redirect('incident.views.about_me')
```

It is a much better approach to use a `form`.

Answer (score 1):

## Django Code to check if the password entered by user matches the actual old password; if it does not, raise validation error in django form. Also, update the password if both of the passwords match.

### Tested on (Django 1.10, Python 3.4)

forms.py

from django import forms

class changePassForm(forms.Form):

```
old_password_flag = True #Used to raise the validation error when it is set to False

old_password = forms.CharField(label="Old Password", min_length=6, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
new_password = forms.CharField(label="New Password", min_length=6, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
re_new_password = forms.CharField(label="Re-type New Password", min_length=6, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

def set_old_password_flag(self): 

#This method is called if the old password entered by user does not match the password in the database, which sets the flag to False

    self.old_password_flag = False

    return 0

def clean_old_password(self, *args, **kwargs):
    old_password = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')

    if not old_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter your old password.")

    if self.old_password_flag == False:
    #It raise the validation error that password entered by user does not match the actucal old password.

        raise forms.ValidationError("The old password that you have entered is wrong.")

    return old_password
```

views.py

def settings(request):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:

    form = changePassForm(request.POST or None)

    old_password = request.POST.get("old_password")
    new_password = request.POST.get("new_password")
    re_new_password = request.POST.get("re_new__password")

    if request.POST.get("old_password"):

        user = User.objects.get(username= request.user.username)

        #User entered old password is checked against the password in the database below.
        if user.check_password('{}'.format(old_password)) == False:
            form.set_old_password_flag()

    if form.is_valid():

        user.set_password('{}'.format(new_password))
        user.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)

        return redirect('settings')

    else:
        return render(request, 'settings.html', {"form": form})

else:
    return redirect('login')
```

settings.html

```
<h1>Settings Page</h1>

<h2>Change Password</h2>

<form action="" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="Submit" value="Update"></input>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/your_views/reset_password/" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Old password" id="old_password" name="old_password" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="New password" id="password1" name="password1" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-new password" id="password2" name="password2" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" style="background: #00A79D;">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>                         
                        </form>
```

Comment: Please add some description about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

***I implemented a method for Sign In with JWT and what it does is:***

1. Fetches the email and password that is send with the request and
   converts it into a string variable
2. I check if the email already
   exists in the custom user model i made.
3. If the user already
   exists, i convert the object model to dictionary so that i can get
   its particular password.
4. In that i match the password
   corresponding to user model and the password that is send with the
   post request.
5. if the email exists in the user model and the password corresponding to that user model matches the password that is sent with the post request i use the pyJWT to make the JWT with my custom data and return the response.
6. In all other cases the email and password don't match and i return "No Match"

> Suppose the request is   {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"12345" }

```
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def signin(request):

    email = list(request.data.values())[0] #gets email value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this xyz@gmail.com
    password = list(request.data.values())[1] #gets password value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this 123

    usr = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() #checks if email exists
    if usr:
      dictionary = User.objects.filter(email=email).values()[0] #converts object to dictionary for accessing data like dictionary["password"] dictionary["first_name"] etc
      if usr and dictionary["password"] == password: #check if email and its corresponing password stored matches the password that is sent
        branch = dictionary["branch"]
        id = dictionary["id"]
        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'email': email,}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        return Response({'token':encoded_jwt,'email':email,'branch':branch,'id':id})
      else: 
        return Response({'No Match'})
    return Response({'No Match'})
```